# log space to linear?

Tags: c++, math

I want to draw vertical lines in an audio display at the following frequencies:

```
float xp[] = {20.f, 30.f, 40.f, 50.f, 60.f, 70.f, 80.f, 90.f, 100.f,
              200.f, 300.f, 400.f, 500.f, 600.f, 700.f, 800.f, 900.f, 1000.f,
              2000.f, 3000.f, 4000.f, 5000.f, 6000.f, 7000.f, 8000.f, 9000.f, 10000.f,
              20000.f
        };
```

They're already logarithmically spaced and I want to convert them to a linear scale such that 20 = 0.0 and 20000 = 1.0. Basically, the opposite of

```
float logspace(float start, float stop, float t)
{
    return start * std::pow(stop/start, t);
}
```

I'd like to create a log2Linear() function to be used like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
{
    // log2linear() would return a normalized value between 20 & 20000
    float normX = log2Linear(20.f, 20000.f, xp[i]);

    float x = normX * widthOfDisplay;
    // draw vertical line at x
}
```

What would `logToLinear(float start, float stop, float t)` look like? Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an example of how logToLinear() is used and pseudo code describing its functionality.

Comment: What's the inverse of log?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: `std::pow(x, t)` is the power function -- it gives you x^^t. So what's it doing in a log function? I'd guess that you did this because you're plotting x as a function of y, so you used the inverse of `log()`? That makes it hard to think about, though — I'd do the math you intend first, and then worry about transforming it for plotting.

Comment: The normal way to scale values to a range [0,1] is `(X - min) / (max - min)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula is very simple

```
  ln(x/20.0) / ln(1000)
```

It transforms 20 to 0, 200 to 1/3, 2000 to 2/3, 20000 to 1

Comment: Perfect. That was it. Thank you. (in C++ terms, it's: std::log(x / 20.f) / std::log(1000.f))